# Kafka 2.5.0 Admin api, what timestamp used in listOffset method?

Tags: apache-kafka

There is a method `listOffset` in [KafkaAdmin API](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html) from [2.5.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7689) version.
This method can return offset by timestamp.

```
/**
 * Used to retrieve the the earliest offset whose timestamp is greater than
 * or equal to the given timestamp in the corresponding partition
 * @param timestamp in milliseconds
 */
public static OffsetSpec forTimestamp(long timestamp) {
    return new TimestampSpec(timestamp);
}
```

And also this method return object `ListOffsetsResultInfo` which has the fields `offset` and `timestamp`.
So my question is -> What timestamp in both cases API mentions?
Does it timestamp of `KafkaRecord` if yes -> can it work with `message.timestamp.type=CreateTime` ?
Or only with `message.timestamp.type=LogAppendTime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When records are sent to Kafka, producers can specify a timestamp or not depending on `message.timestamp.type`. If the producer did not specify a timestamp, Kafka will set it to its current time. So in the end, each Record has a single value for timestamp.

The `timestamp` argument of `OffsetSpec.forTimestamp()` is checked against the timestamp of the Kafka record by the broker.

It applies regardless if the Record's timestamp came from `CreateTime` (provided by producers) or `LogAppendTime` provided by the broker.

Comment: Thx for the answer @Mickeal Maison, but CreatedTimestamp can be reordered, does it have any influence on correctness?

Comment: I mean forTimestamp spec return offset closet to this greater or equal to this timestamp. But if records in the partition will be reordered by timestamp, which one it will return first from the tail from the head of the partition?

Comment: Record are not ordered by timestamp. They are ordered by order of arrival. Kafka will return the offset of the record with the smallest offset that matches the timestamp requested